# how should i do when i want to create a file log in tmux using bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, tmux

This is log from test.sh and i want to record this to a file log

> DEBUG[11-21|10:45:27.891] Persisted trie from memory database
>   size=55.30kB time=2.099162ms   gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livesize=0.00B
>   DEBUG[11-21|10:45:28.052] Persisted trie from memory database
>   size=55.15kB time=2.124362ms  gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livesize=0.00B
>   DEBUG[11-21|10:45:28.214] Persisted trie from memory database
>   size=55.45kB time=2.143965ms  gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livesize=0.00B
>   DEBUG[11-21|10:45:28.375] Persisted trie from memory database
>   size=56.19kB time=2.206321ms  gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livesize=0.00B
>   DEBUG[11-21|10:45:28.535] Persisted trie from memory database
>   size=55.15kB time=2.296182ms  gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livesize=0.00B
>   DEBUG[11-21|10:45:28.698] Persisted trie from memory database
>   size=55.15kB time=2.24339ms  gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livesize=0.00B

Comment: test.sh > file.log